# How to force jQuery function to finish fading animation before updating text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

I'm developing a javascript application that receives messages from my python program which is linked to a chat room. The goal is for the javascript application to update the text of an html paragraph to "thank you + user" for each chat message, fade in, delay, then fade out.

My issue is that if I receive several chat messages at once, the paragraph text updates immediately for each chat sender, and doesn't wait for the fading animation.

Right now, for each chat message, I am calling the function below every time I receive a chat line.

```
function fadeInfadeOutMessage(name) {
    $('#twitchname').html("Thank you <br> " +  name).fadeIn(timeFade[0]).delay(timeFade[1]).fadeOut(timeFade[2])
}
```

What changes do I need to make to not allow the html to be updated until the fading sequence finishes?

Comment: Use promises. https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So promises allow you to complete actions and then do something afterwards. So looking at the example below I make my message div promise he wont do anything until his animation queue is complete. The first promise fires immediately because he wasn't doing anything to start. A promise will always fire immediately if there is nothing to do. So no matter how many times I click the button it always waits to complete what it was doing before it starts again.

Source: https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pxospknj/

JS:

```
// No changes to this function. Its our callback now.
// The thing that happens after promises complete
function fadeInfadeOutMessage(name) {
    $('#somemessage').html("Thank you <br> " +  name).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
}


$("#somebutton").on("click",
    function () {
    var element = $("#somemessage");

    // Make the element promise us that when its done doing whatever
    // its doing it will complete what we just asked it to do which
    // is animate again.
    element.promise().done(
        function () {
        fadeInfadeOutMessage("gary");
      }
    )
  }
);
```

HTML:

```
<button id="somebutton">go</button>
<div id="somemessage"></div>
```

**======================================**

OK, so the default queue is for effects so updating the HTML happens immediately while the animations are queued. Buuuuut if we pass the string in and fake out the queue with a super fast animation and then update the html during the callback before doing our real animations we can pull it off.

At this point promises aren't even needed because of the default effects queue but they are super powerful when dealing with async code so keep them in mind and read up on them for future use.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pxospknj/4/

HTML:

```
<button id="somebutton">go</button>
<div id="somemessage"></div>
```

JS:

```
function fadeInfadeOutMessage(name) {
  // Immediate hide so we know its hidden before updating and we can use
  // the callback to update html while taking advantage of the effects queue
  $('#somemessage').hide(0,
    function() {
      $(this).html("Thank you <br> " + name);
    }).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
  // Proceed as normal with other animations
}

// Init our count so we see different strings updating properly
var count = 0;
$("#somebutton").on("click",
  function() {
    // Make sure we pass in string so it has scope
    fadeInfadeOutMessage("gary" + count);
    // Update count
    count++;
  }
);
```

Comment: Slightly modified your code, in the jsfiddle. Note that it will skip numbers (which is now the stage that I'm at, it will thank the first person, but then it will skip to wherever it is numerically). How can I not skip?

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    animate('gary' + i);
}

function animate(name) {
 var element = $("#somemessage");
    element.promise().done(
     function () {
       fadeInfadeOutMessage(name);
      }
    )
}

function fadeInfadeOutMessage(name) {
    $('#somemessage').html("Thank you <br> " +  name).fadeIn(300).delay(400).fadeOut(300);
}

Comment: That's fine. I just was giving a simple example for promises. Do with it what you will! Good luck!

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't clear, it was a question. The output is "gary0", "gary9", "gary9", "gary9", "gary9", "gary9", "gary9", "gary9"... instead of 1,2,3,4,.... would you be able to answer how can I have it properly queue ?

Comment: I'll need to look at the code but most likely a scope problem. I'm literally getting on a plane right now so I'll need to look when I land. I'll be in the air for a few hours.

Comment: @frankL sorry it took so long. Busy weekend. check out the update to my answer and the fiddle and you can see how to pull off what you want. Let me know if you have any questions.